# Why does the object I make 3D in PS CC 2015 not take on the same color as the front, for all the sides?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d

When I turn an object 3D in PS CC 2015 I want the whole object to be the same color but the front is in color and the other sides are gray. How do i make the whole 3D object the same color?

Full disclosure, this yellow layer/object was a stroke that i separated and made a separate layer. It's a raster object. I want the whole 3D object to be yellow with shading from the lighting.

Please help. thanks[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing the light color? color of the 3D object/faces? Can you tell us what you tried that didn't work?

Comment: @luciano - I guess that worked. I changed the lighting to yellow and it seems to have solved my problem. thanks. 

But I don't understand why the tutorials i've seen never have the 3D sides start out gray. They're always the same color as the front of the element.

And I turned live type into a 3D object in the past and it kept all the sides the same color. Wondering why it turns the sides gray in other instances ? It's an extra step to change the lighting color that i wish i didn't have to go through. Any insight is appreciated. thanks

Comment: @luciano - Actually, i think i spoke too soon. I tried to change the light color on a new element to cover the gray sides and it's not working. The front is white and i want the sides to be white so i changed the light to white but you can still tell that the sides are a lot darker because the grey on all the sides is so dark. How can i attach a photo to this post you you can see an image of what it looks like?